How to restore desktop color settings?
OS is Debian 12. Video driver is Nvidia 525.147.05.
I'm trying to play an older game via wine that uses DirectX (Diablo 2). I launched the game in windowed mode, but when I did so, the colors of the entire screen changed. (brightness, contrast, gamma as far as I can tell). The game runs fine, but when quitting the game, the previous color settings are unfortunately not restored.
As a separate incident, this happened with Zandronum also, I accidentally selected full screen, and it nuked my color settings, the contrast looks super high now. I really need to get it back to the previous settings.
What is going on here? How can an application change the color settings for the entire desktop? How would I determine what settings exactly were changed? I don't see any sort of settings for brightness or contrast etc. in nvidia-settings.
How would I try to restore the color settings to how they looked before I launched the game? Is there any way to "lock" these color settings so that random applications can't change them? I could understand a single application changing the settings for its own colors, but interfering with the entire desktop is quite bizarre.
Color depth looks fine:
xwininfo -root | grep Depth
  Depth: 24

Is it possible that somehow some software changed settings on the monitor itself? If this is possible, how do I prevent that from happening in the future?

What kind of colour alteration are we speaking of here? Is that the kind as set by xgamma or xrand --gamma?

I wish I knew. All I can see is the colors look drastically different, basically much much higher contrast.

On which DE happen? Did you try others? On GNOME I'd compare after/before of the dconf dump /. You are using wine? Which version?

Yet another theme. Wine on what archetechture (x86, arm)?

Not just wine, this happens randomly with fullscreen programs, usually games, ie, Zandronum. x86-64.

The DE is mate.
